# Are Riemannian Geometry and Differential topology the same thing?

Tags: soft-question, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

I'm not an expert on the subject, but I was wondering what's the difference between "Riemannian Geometry" and "Differential topology". To me the names suggest they're different things, but looking through some of the books preview they seem to have similar content.

Can anyone clarify? Is maybe one a subset of the other? What sorts of problems do they allow to solve that the other doesn't etc.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't think "differential geometry" and "Reimannian Geometry" are the same thing.

Comment: Like the OP says in the duplicate: "Introduction to differential geometry (for me it should be called introduction to Riemannian manifolds)." So I think the very nice answers there are interesting for this question too, and worth reading.

Comment: In addition to the link, you deserve a 1-word answer: "No"

Comment: @MikeMiller "no" to which question? I've asked 2 questions.

Comment: @user8469759: No on both questions.